# Implementing a Softmax output layer with cross-entropy loss

Tags: c, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, softmax

I am playing with this repo (https://github.com/SnailWalkerYC/LeNet-5_Speed_Up) and try to learn NN details. This repo implemented LeNet5 in C and CUDA. I am focusing on the CPU part now and its code in seq/. One particular place I am getting lost is this function in seq/lenet.c

```
static inline void softmax(double input[OUTPUT], double loss[OUTPUT], int label, int count){
      double inner = 0; 
      for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
           double res = 0;
           for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j){
              res += exp(input[j] - input[i]);
           }
           loss[i] = 1. / res;
           inner -= loss[i] * loss[i];
       }
       inner += loss[label];
       for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
          loss[i] *= (i == label) - loss[i] - inner;
       }
}
```

Because there are no comments, I spent some time to understand this function. Finally I figured it that it is computing the derivatives of a MSE loss function with respect to input to a softmax layer.

Then I am trying to use a cross-entropy loss function together with softmax so I came out with the following function to replace the above one.

```
static inline void softmax(double input[OUTPUT], double loss[OUTPUT], int label, int count)
{
    double inner = 0;
    double max_input = -INFINITY;

    // Find the maximum input value to prevent numerical instability
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if (input[i] > max_input)
            max_input = input[i];
    }

    // Compute softmax and cross-entropy loss
    double sum_exp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        double exp_val = exp(input[i] - max_input);
        sum_exp += exp_val;
        loss[i] = exp_val;
    }

    double softmax_output[OUTPUT];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        loss[i] /= sum_exp;
        softmax_output[i] = loss[i];
    }

    // Compute cross-entropy loss and derivatives
    inner = -log(softmax_output[label]);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        
    loss[i] = softmax_output[i] - (i == label);
    }
}
```

However, with my version of softmax() function, the MNIST recognition didn't work. The original version achieved a >96% accuracy. What's wrong with my code for cross-entropy loss?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll answer my own question.

I managed to make the cross-entropy loss work with softmax. There are two places that need to be tweaked:

1. The derivative of cross-entropy w.r.t. to inputs of softmax has form of (prediction - label), as seen in many places. However, the code in this particular repo has to be

```
loss[i] = (i == label) - softmax_output[i]; // opposite of the common form
```

instead of

```
loss[i] = softmax_output[i] - (i == label); // conforms to the common form
```

This is because the way this CNN updates the weights and biases is counterintuitive:

```
double k = ALPHA / batchSize;
FOREACH(i, GETCOUNT(LeNet5))
    ((double *)lenet)[i] += k * buffer[i];
```

So either use the opposite form of the loss derivative or change weight update to

```
   ((double *)lenet)[i] -= k * buffer[i];
```

2. Even with the above fix, this MNIST CNN still did not work. Sometimes the loss during training just did not drop. Another peculiar thing I noticed is the learning rate (ALPHA in the code). This code hardcoded learning rate at `0.5`. Most places I've seen used `0.1`.

With above 1) and 2), the model now predicts at >%96 level consistently.

Well, I have learned quite a lot during this process.